# Внешний вид progress

Tags: css

Сейчас я уже жалею, что решил использовать этот тег, но что-то изменять уже поздно. Как изменить внешний вид progress?

```
.progress_main {
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;

    background: yellow;
    
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value { background: red; }
```

Что я упускаю? Убираю background из класса, пропадает вообще фон прогресс бара. Убираю из progress::-webkit-progress-value, он становится зеленым. Я сдаюсь.

Answer (score 2):

Для всех браузеров на движке webkit:

```css
progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

::-webkit-progress-inner-element {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: orange;
}

::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<progress value="70" max="100"/><br/>
```

Для всех браузеров mozilla:

```css
::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
}

:indeterminate::-moz-progress-bar {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<progress value="30" max="100">30%</progress>
<progress max="100">Indeterminate</progress>
```

Для Edge и IE:

```css
progress::-ms-fill {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<progress value="70" max="100"/>
```

Comment: Видимо лучше всего сделать по классике через div